# How to redirect visitors to unique page cache directories based on subdomain via Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have a rails app which is handling requests from both `m.host.com` and `host.com`. If the request comes in to `m.host.com`, the rails app page cache dir is `/public/cache/m/`, and if the request comes to `host.com` the page cache dir is `/public/cache/www/`.

The problem is that the first `RewriteCond` is being matched for both requests to `m.host.com` and `host.com`.

```
# if the `HTTP_HOST` starts with "m." (m.host.com), look for the cache in /cache/m/...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\..*
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/$ /cache/m/$1.html [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ /cache/m/$1.html [QSA]

# if not, look for the cache in /cache/www/...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\..*
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/$ /cache/www/$1.html [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ /cache/www/$1.html [QSA]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
# if the `HTTP_HOST` starts with "m." (m.host.com), look for the cache in /cache/m/...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ /cache/m/$1.html [L,QSA]

# if not, look for the cache in /cache/www/...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ /cache/www/$1.html [L,QSA]
```

By adding the 'L' to the parameters you tell the parser that the current RewriteRule is the last one applied to the current request.

Also a RewriteCond only applies to the single next RewriteRule, that's why your rewrites were the same for any request, the parser would apply both second RewriteRules to the request.

Comment: Thanks, I had to add one more rule to make it all work: `RewriteRule ^/$ /index [QSA]`. This way it would find `index.html` later when it ran the rules you suggested.